# how to remove and keep only the updated files after running git mergetool

Tags: git

I'm trying to do git merge and ran into conflict. I used: `git mergetool --tool=emerge`

This has produced four files
`style_Backup.css`: old code

`style_Base.css`: old code

`style_Local.css`: it's an empty file

`style_Remote.css`: Has some changes

How do I go about this? Should I manually delete the file and rename them?

Answer (score 0):

Try first, if you don't want to complete the merge, a `git merge --abort`

If extra files remains, clean them with `clean -n` (to get a preview) / `clean -f` (to actually remove them)